# Caption Shortcode: what filter to change the image size?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, images, filters, shortcode

Doing a huge overhaul of my website mainly for page load performance, I want to filter the caption shortcode in `the_content` to load the thumbnail version of the image if `wp_is_mobile()` returns `true`. If not, load the size set in the shortcode.

What is the right filter to do so?

Comment: and I did disable srcset because they were always loading the regular-sized image, even on mobiles...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should [read this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/img_caption_shortcode). It explains how to achieve what you are looking for. Be aware of `wp_is_mobile()` function if you are using any cache system, it would result in some unexpected behavior.